# Show that the function $f(z) = \overline{z}$ (complex conjugate) doesn’t have a derivative anywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Any hints? I know that $z$ conjugate = $x-y$, has derivatives $1$ for $x$ and $-1$ for $y$. How does it not have a derivative?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Please write down the definition of what it means for a complex function to have a complex derivative.  You need to proceed directly from the definition.

Comment: Please use [MthaJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: The definition of a derivative is $\lim \limits_{z \to 1}$ \frac{f(z+hz) - f(z)}{hz}, if we plug in our values in this equation, then,
$\lim \limits_{z \to 1}$ \ frac{(\bar{z}+h\bar{z}) - \bar{z)}{h\bar{z}}
Which works out to be 0. Does 0 mean that there is no derivative?

Comment: Do you know about the Cauchy–Riemann equations and complex differentiability at all? If not, you will need to read a little bit about the basics before attempting this problem. (By the way, $\overline{z}=x-iy$, not $x-y$.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied, then there is no complex derivative. Is this proof sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've nearly answered your own question. The value of the derivative would be a complex number. Should that complex number be $+1$ or $-1\text{?}$ If you approach $z$ from one direction you get one number and from another direction, another number. The derivative of a function $f$ at $z$ is
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{w\,\to\,z} \frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}.
$$
If you get one limit as $w$ approaches $z$ from one direction and another limit as $w$ approaches $z$ from another direction, then the limit above does not exist; thus the derivative above does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and giving another way to look at this. What thoguh, in this case f(w) and w be?

Comment: @PlatinumMaths : $z$ is the point in the domain at which $f'(z)$ is to be evaluated. $w$ is the bound variable that approaches $z.$ To say that $\lim_{w\,\to\,a} g(w) = b$ means that $g(w)$ can be made as close to $b$ as desired by making $w$ close enough, but not equal, to $a.$ The bottom-line answer, $b,$ does not depend on any quantity called $w.$ Suppose one sees the expression $\sum_{w\,=\,1}^3 w^3.$ That would mean $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2,$ and the expression $1^2+2^2 + 3^2$ does not depend on any quantity called $w.$ That is the nature of bound variables.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overline{z+h}-\overline z}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overline{h}}{h}$$ is already enough to show that the derivative exists everywhere or nowhere.

Then with real variables

$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\overline{u}}{u}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u}{u}=1,\\\lim_{v\to0}\frac{\overline{iv}}{iv}=\lim_{v\to0}\frac{-iv}{iv}=-1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I managed to also work out that it turns out to be h/h. But how does that show that the derivative doesn't exist?

Also why could it also show that the derivative exists everywhere?

Comment: @PlatinumMaths: $1\ne-1$, no ? And isn't $z$ gone ?

Comment: It does *not* "turn out to be $h/h$" !!!

Comment: So what if 1 is not equal to -1? 1 is with respect to x and -1 is with respect to y? It does turn out to be h(conjugate)/h(conjugate)

Comment: @PlatinumMaths: neither. But it is in front of your eyes !

Comment: Hmm... interesting